# Do growing effects on creatures (such as Enlarge Person and Righteous Might) stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, creature-size, bloodline

Actually nothing in the rules says anything about this, while anything affecting the size of weapons seems to not stack with other kinds of growing effects. It is mentioned for the [Growing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/growing) weapon special ability and the [Overcompensation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/rite-publishing---3rd-party-spells/o/overcompensation) spell that they don't stack with any other effect of the same kind, for example you cannot make a Medium weapon grow to Huge size with Enlarge Person on yourself and the Growing special ability.

Then I found multiple ways for a character to temporarily grow in size :

- [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) : 1st level arcane spell, exactly what it says on the tin, affects humanoids only ;
- [Righteous Might](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/righteous-might) : 5th level divine spell, comes with other benefits than just growing, affects the caster only ;
- [Demonic Bulk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo---bloodrager-bloodlines/abyssal)
  : a Bloodrager bloodrage power from the Abyssal bloodline, same effect as Enlarge Person but personal only and not limited by type.

In all these cases, there is no disclaimer of the same kind. Does this mean that these effects can stack on the same character ?

Answer (score 10):

No, as both Enlarge Person and Righteous Might say:

> Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack.

And Demonic Bulk references Enlarge Person except the target doesn't need to be a humanoid, so that would also be covered.

Answer (score 2):

The spell [*enlarge person*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/enlargePerson.html#enlarge-person) says, "Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack." The spell [*righteous might*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/righteousMight.html#righteous-might) says, "Magical effects that increase size do not stack." The bloodrager's [abyssal bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines/paizo---bloodrager-bloodlines/abyssal) special ability demonic bulk is a supernatural ability (hence magical) that's based on the spell *enlarge person*, so it won't stack *twice*.

Also, the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u) includes this exchange:

> **Question:** Size increases and effective size increases: How does damage work if I have various effects that change my actual size, my effective size, and my damage dice?
>
> **Answer:** As per the rules on size changes, size changes do not stack, so if you have multiple size changing effects (for instance an effect that increases your size by one step and another that increases your size by two steps), only the largest applies. The same is true of effective size increases (which includes “deal damage as if they were one size category larger than they actually are,” “your damage die type increases by one step,” and similar language). They don’t stack with each other, just take the biggest one. However, you can have one of each and they do work together (for example, *enlarge person* increasing your actual size to Large and a *bashing* shield increasing your shield’s effective size by two steps, for a total of 2d6 damage).

If you're willing to wade through 200+ posts on this topic, you can do that [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qusu&page=1?Magical-Nonmagical-size-increases-and-stacking), but, in short, the FAQ ruling means that you can have running simultaneously the largest *actual* size increase and the largest *effective* size increase. For example, a Medium human that's been the subject of an *enlarge person* spell and whose greatsword had been the subject of the spell [*lead blades*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lead-blades) has a greatsword that deals 4d6 points of damage *sans* modifiers (like a Huge greatsword does). However, I think were the same *enlarged* human to activate his  *+1 [growing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/growing) greatsword*, the greatsword would deal only 3d6 points of damage (like a Large weapon does), the *+1 growing greatsword* already having had its size *actually* increased. (Nonetheless, while active, the magic weapon special ability *growing* would allow that *enlarged* human to use combat maneuvers against creatures he normally couldn't, so it's not a total loss.)

The only way I'm aware of to *instantaneously* increase a creature's size (i.e. immune to *dispel magic* and lasting forever) is by drawing the 5 of diamonds from a [*harrow deck of many things*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/deck-of-many-things-harrow).