# Wild Shape + Powerful Shape

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, grapple

This is a grappling related question. As a 10th level druid, would it be possible to wild shape into a Huge animal, cast Animal growth on yourself thus going to Gargantuan then be further pushed to Colossal (not in terms of size but strictly for CMB) by way of Powerful Shape? I would imagine this would make the druid quite effective a grappler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unfortunately, it's not possible

The supernatural ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) is an effect like that of the spells *[beast shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape/) et al.* of the [transmutation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation) subschool polymorph and "other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell."

Further, the spells *beast shape et al.* on which the supernatural ability wild shape is based don't change the caster's type. Unless the druid possessed the type animal to begin with, the druid, despite having the form of an animal, still can't target himself with a spell like [*animal growth*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth/) because of the spell's entry *Target: One animal (Gargantuan or smaller)*.

The feat [Powerful Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/powerful-shape/) changes neither of these restrictions.

Comment: I did not know a druid could not cast animal growth on himself. Can one cast strong jaw on himself?

Comment: @Atalius Strong Jaw only changes the damage (which can't stack with other things like Improved Natural Attack).  It doesn't actually change your size, so it can apply to Wild Shape.

Comment: @Atalius WeirdFrog is correct. The spell *strong jaw* is an effective size increase and a creature typically benefits from only one *actual* size increase and only one *virtual* (or effective) size increase (in each case, usually the biggest). You can read more about this weirdness [here.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78744/8610)

Comment: So powerful shape still would apply for CMB purposes you would be the next size up from Huge correct?

Comment: Yes, you would count as a Gargantuan creature, including the ability to use Grab on Gargantuan creatures.