# Which of these size enlarging options for a barbarian stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, barbarian

I'm just interested in theorycrafting. The barbarian class provides two mechanisms of growing a character's size one step:

- Titan Mauler's *Titanic Rage*
- the bloodrage power: *Abyssal Rage*

There are also additional sources of increasing one's size. Using the eldritch heritage feat line, one can pick the sorcerer bloodline ORC and thus gain *Power of Giants*.

Of course, the friendly mage cast or one, via items, can employ *Enlarge Person* to help a bit.

Which of these options stack and what size category will be gained?

Comment: Is your goal to increase a Barbarian to the largest possible size or do you want to know which of these stack?

Comment: Actually, I'll just remove the bonus question and this won't need closing.  Feel free to post that as a separate question, though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78734/8610).

Comment: @HeyICanChan That question is about several specific game elements not mentioned here, both of which say they don't stack with other size increases.

Comment: @ObliviousSage That question is about size increases generally, the basic question remains the same, and *enlarge person* is mentioned in both. (Also, I did *not* VTC this question—despite being able to close it unilaterally—because, while there's overlap, I figured I'd let the community decide if it's *sufficient* overlap. It just seemed a shame to not even recognize that the site's addressed this similar issue before, and by calling attention to the other question in such a way, it goes on the Linked panel.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, of course, the principle obstacle to stacking size alteration is:

> Multiple magical effects that increase size don't stack.

(from the CRB in the Enlarge person description)

So, only one of the magical effects will increase the character's size.  All of the effects you have listed are magical in nature, either because they are a supernatural ability, a spell-like ability, or a spell.  The final size of the character in question is one larger than whatever their base size was.

Lastly, if you are playing with the Dreamscarred Press psionic rules, the Expansion power was ported over verbatim from 3.5, and provides the even harsher rule:

> Multiple effects that increase size do not stack

rendering whether or not the effects are magical moot.